# How to understand the results of rows between 2 preceding and current row?

Tags: sql, oracle, window-functions

My SQL query is:

```
SELECT time, buy,
  avg(buy) OVER (ORDER BY time rows between 1 preceding and current row) as average_2,
  avg(buy) OVER (ORDER BY time rows between 2 preceding and current row) as average_3
FROM my_table;
```

I'm trying to understand these window functions. I used some test data and got results:

```
TIME                       BUY  AVERAGE_2  AVERAGE_3
------------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2019-05-05 10:05:19          1          1          1
2019-05-05 10:05:22          2        1.5        1.5
2019-05-05 10:05:25          3        2.5          2
2019-05-05 10:05:27          4        3.5          3
```

I need to know: how do I get these results? Specially `average_3`?

What is the difference between `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` and `rows between 2 preceding and current row`? I read many explanations from the internet, now I'm confused because they have explained with different syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your question "What is the difference between ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 
CURRENT ROW and rows between 2 preceding and current row ?"

In average_3 you get the average between the two previous rows and the current row, the same happens in average_2 but only with a previous row, but it is better to see a good example of that.

This [post](https://stevestedman.com/2012/03/rows-preceding-and-following-in-tsql-2012/) by Steve Stedman is really good, and it gives you a good example of that.

Answer (score 9):

For the first row (earliest time), there are no preceding rows, so both `between 1 preceding and current row` and `between 2 preceding and current row` only actually find the current row. Both averages are therefore the average of a single value, 1, which is of course 1.

For the second row, there is only one preceding row, so both `between 1 preceding and current row` and `between 2 preceding and current row` only actually find the current row (2) and that single preceding row (1). Both averages are therefor the average of the same two values, 2 and 1, which is 1.5 (i.e. (2+1)/2)).

For the third row, there are now two preceding rows. This time:

- `between 1 preceding and current row` finds the current row (3) and the immediately preceding row (2), and that average is calculated as (3+2)/2 which is 2.5. Any earlier preceding rows are ignored, so 1 isn't included in the calculation.
- `between 2 preceding and current row` finds the current row (3) and both preceding rows (2 and 1), and that average is calculated as (3+2+1)/3 which is 2.

For the fourth row, there are again two preceding rows. This time:

- `between 1 preceding and current row` finds the current row (4) and the immediately preceding row (3), and that average is calculated as (4+3)/2 which is 3.5. Any earlier preceding rows are ignored, so neither 2 nor 1 are included in the calculation.
- `between 2 preceding and current row` finds the current row (4) and both preceding rows (3 and 2), and that average is calculated as (4+3+2)/3 which is 3. Any earlier preceding rows are ignored, so 1 isn't included in the calculation.

If you were also calculating `between unbounded preceding and current row`, which is the default if you don't specify that at all, then *all* preceding rows are included. That makes no difference for the first two rows; but for the third and fourth the 'any earlier preceding rows are ignored' part would not be true. The average would therefore still be 1 for row 1 and 1.5 for row 2; and would be 2 for row 3 ((3+2+1)/3; and would be 2.5 for row 4 ((4+3+2+1)/4).

[Read more](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html).

Comment: Very well explained!!

Comment: This is very clear. Also, I wanted to ask that instead of  `between 2 preceding and current row` can I also say  `OVER(ORDER BY 'time' ROWS 2 PRECEDING) to keep it simple?